# how to use math round js in gauge bottomText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gauge

how to make rounding with math round from ajax value to bottom Text gauge?

this is my gauge js

```
 var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart("gaugeDetails2", {
                    "type": "gauge",
                    "theme": "light",
                    "axes": [{
                            "axisThickness": 1,
                            "axisAlpha": 0.2,
                            "tickAlpha": 0.2,
                            "labelsEnabled": false,
                            "bands": [{
                                    "balloonText": "Good",
                                    "color": "#84b761",
                                    "endValue": 60,
                                    "startValue": 0
                                }, {
                                    "balloonText": "Fair",
                                    "color": "#fdd400",
                                    "endValue": 120,
                                    "startValue": 61
                                }, {
                                    "balloonText": "Poor",
                                    "color": "#cc4748",
                                    "endValue": 180,
                                    "startValue": 121
                                }],
                            "bottomText": data.data3['KPI_REALISASI_PROGRAM'],
                            "bottomTextYOffset": -10,
                            "endValue": 180
                        }],
                    "arrows": [{"value": data.data3['KPI_REALISASI_PROGRAM']}],
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": false
                    }
                });
```

I want to round up data.data3['KPI_REALISASI_PROGRAM'] with math round, if im using Math.round(data.data3['KPI_REALISASI_PROGRAM'].5); the gauge cant be show up. please help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use math.ceil for rounding up:

```
Math.ceil(data.data3['KPI_REALISASI_PROGRAM']);
```